# Could not parse the remainder django pybb

Tags: django, django-templates

trying to install PyBB on Django, when trying to start forum page got error, did the same thing on new installed virtual machine everything works fine, looks like problem somewhere on my Djando, what might be wrong?

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /forum/

Could not parse the remainder: ':pybb_category_add' from 'admin:pybb_category_add'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/
Django Version:     1.5
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Could not parse the remainder: ':pybb_category_add' from 'admin:pybb_category_add'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in __init__, line 570
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/denis/hosts/blog',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_simple_captcha-0.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']


Error during template rendering

In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybb/templates/pybb/index.html, error at line 17
Could not parse the remainder: ':pybb_category_add' from 'admin:pybb_category_add'
7   {% with extra_crumb="Forum" %}{% include "pybb/breadcrumb.html" %}{% endwith %}
8   {% endblock %}
9   
10  {% block content %}
11  {% if categories %}
12  {% for category in categories %}
13  {% include 'pybb/category.html' %}
14  {% endfor %}
15  {% else %}
16  <h2>{% trans "Forum categories are not created" %}</h2>
17  <a href="{% url admin:pybb_category_add %}">{% trans "Add a category now" %}</a>
18  {% endif %}
19  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
20  <div id='mark-all-as-read'>
21  <a href='{% url pybb:mark_all_as_read %}'>
22  {% trans "Mark all forums as read" %}
23  </a>
24  </div>
25  {% endif %}
26  {% endblock content %}
27
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using quotes when using the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:pybb_category_add' %}">{% trans "Add a category now" %}</a>%}
...
<a href="{% url 'pybb:mark_all_as_read' %}">
```

From the docs:

> The first argument is a path to a view function in the format
>   package.package.module.function. It can be a quoted literal or any
>   other context variable.